# How do i declare a function which takes a variable of a yet unidentified type as parameter

Tags: delphi, types, declaration, lazarus

the question is as the title reads. O get the error: Type identifier expected, which (i think) comes from the function declaration being read before the type declaration.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    //other declarations
    function ItemThere(x: TItem): boolean; // here it says TItem is unknown
  end;

type
  TItem = class
    Name : String;
    Description : String;
    constructor Create;
  end;
```

Also i would like let you know that i am a rather unexperienced programmer. 
How can i fix this? Should i just move the declaration of TItem above TForm1? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should take a look to Generics, they are intended for this cases. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Overview_of_Generics

Comment: Why don't you move the declaration of the 'TItem' to above the form, so that the compiler knows what it is.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz's idea is the best for a novice.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think i can fix the problem with the new information. I will still try to use Generics, how else will i get better.

Comment: Also look at the [forward definition of a class](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse33.html) - it is useful for some specific cases.

Comment: Generics aren't going to help. Either re-order the declarations, or use a forward declaration

Comment: BTW the right solution: just move the `TItem` class to the another unit and include it to the `uses` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi's compiler needs to know about the type *before* it's used. There are two ways to accomplish that with your code.

1. Move the declaration above the place it's first used:

   ```
   type
     TItem = class
       Name : String;
       Description : String;
       constructor Create;
     end;

     TForm1 = class(TForm)
       //other declarations
       function ItemThere(x: TItem): boolean; 
     end;
   ```
2. Use what is known as a [forward declaration](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse33.html), which basically just tells the compiler that you're using a class which you'll define later (within the same type declaration section):

   ```
   type
     TItem = class;              // forward declaration

     TForm1 = class(TForm)
       //other declarations
       function ItemThere(x: TItem): boolean; 
     end;

     TItem = class               // Now define the class itself
       Name : String;
       Description : String;
       constructor Create;
     end;
   ```

Comment: Forward classes need to be defined in the same `type` declaration.  The `type` keyword for TForm1 and TItem (full definition) need to be removed.

Comment: @Jason: That's not my experience, and it's not what is demonstrated in dozens of units in the Delphi VCL code. Is this a restriction of FP that doesn't exist in Delphi?

Comment: My experience is the opposite.  Does the above compile for you?  It does not for me.  I get a compiler error `Type 'TItem' is not yet completely defined`.

Comment: @Jason: Nope, you're right. Just double-checked, and my recollection was wrong. I've edited the post accordingly. Thanks for the catch. :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for :D